# Glassmapper: Map target item from Link field

Tags: glass-mapper

Im using Sitecore with Glassmapper and in my template I have a drop link field that I'm using to link to sitecore items of a specific template (X). In glass mapper's generated .cs this field gets generated as a Link field and that has a targetID GUID to the sitecore item of template X.

I was wondering, is it possible for glass mapper to generate the type of the Link as a template X. Instead of me running a get on the itemid each time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could select the template field listed on your solution explorer and then set the Custom Data as (don't forget to re-generate code):

```
type=IYourTemplate
```

[image]